# Passing validation data in Vue.js to slot

Tags: vuejs2

I have just started using Vue.js and want to use vee-validator plugin so I don't have to re-invent the wheel. Whether you use vee-validator or not I am sure you Vue wizards out there will know how to deal with this situation.

To help keep my code clean so that the update one place update everywhere idea stands true I am trying to make some custom components that are just nicely styled and wrapped HTML inputs.

In this simple example I just have the one TextInput but the idea would be to follow the same format but have other types of inputs, textareas, selects etc.

I have been trying to work with this sample from Vee-Validate but the sample is not very clear and it is also not exactly what I am trying to do.
http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html#component-example

So my main app is this:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">New Post</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <inputWrapper label="My Label" icon="fa-user">
                        <textInput name="test" placeholder="Edit me"></textInput>
                    </inputWrapper>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
            }
        }
</script>
```

Then I have the InputWrapper.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': errors.has('email') }">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>{{ label }}</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" v-if="icon"><i class="fa fa-lg " v-bind:class="icon"></i></span>
                <slot></slot> <!-- Input element passed from parent -->
            </div>
            <small class="help-block" v-show="errors.has('email')">
                <strong>{{ errors.first('email') }}</strong>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['label', 'icon'],

        data(){
            return {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my TextInput.vue:

```
<template>
    <input 
        v-bind:id="name"
        v-bind:name="name"
        v-bind:placeholder="placeholder"

        v-on:keyup="onInput"

        class="form-control" />
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'placeholder', 'type'],

        data(){
            return {
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onInput(e) {
                const value = e.target.value;
                this.$emit('input', value);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have been tinkering with the onInput() method in TextInput.vue but am not sure this is what I really should be doing.

Notice the InputWrapper.vue file has the 'errors' errorBag however it is not displaying the errors. I presume this is because the errors.has() and errors.first() do not exist in the same component as what is being validated.

How can I get InputWrapper to show errors comming from my custom TextInput component?

I have added v-validate="'required|email'" to the custom component call in the main app with no luck and also tried it in the TextInput.vue file with no luck. And unfortunately the docs on vee-validator dont adiquitly describe what data-vv-value-path really is, so I don't know what I should be putting in there as a value.

Comment: I am open to suggestions on other pre existing validators or the option of doing my own if it will make my life easier for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your text input name prop should be 'email' instead of 'test':

```
    <textInput name="email" placeholder="Edit me"></textInput>
```

because that's the error you're looking for in your InputWrapper.vue:

```
    <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': errors.has('email') }">
```

As the documentation says

> The plugin augments your Vue instance with a private validator object and a public errors data object.

the same object should be accessible across all components.

Answer (score 0):

You can try injecting your main app `$validator` into you children components `InputWrapper.vue` and `TextInput.vue`:

```
export default {
  inject: ['$validator']
}
```

...but slots are not [much supported](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/325), you may have to use an event bus instance if injecting doesn't work:

```
const bus = new Vue({})
// ...
bus.$emit('value_changed', newValue)
// ...
bus.$on('value_changed', (value) => {
  // do something
})
```